# how to parse a simple xml file to a readable format

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, xml-simple

Perl newbie here. Can someone kindly show me how to use perl to extract data from this xml file and format the output anyway i would need? Would I use XML::Simple or open this as a fh and split it somehow? thank you.

Documentation for using [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) doesn't seem simple to me.

For example I have a small xml file that looks like this.

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.5" encoding="UTF-8"?><org.apache.Content duration="277135" count="51" numDirs="50" bytesUsed="110133451"/>
```

I would like to convert attribute="value" pairs to be readable like csv file, `:`  or however, i want to print it out.

Ex:

```
duration:277135 count:51 numDirs:50 bytesUsed:110133451
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use XML::Simple - Easy API to maintain XML (esp config files) or 
see XML::Twig - A perl module for processing huge XML documents in tree mode.

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = q~<?xml version="1.5" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<org.apache.Content duration="277135" count="51" numDirs="50" bytesUsed="110133451"/>~;

print $xml,$/;

my $data = XMLin($xml);

print Dumper( $data );

foreach my $attributes (keys %{$data}){
  print"$attributes : ${$data}{$attributes}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
bytesUsed : 110133451
numDirs : 50
count : 51
duration : 277135
```

Comment: thank you for your help. can `$xml` be read in as a file too if the contents were in a separate xml file? how would i do that?

Comment: yes you can do that by just providing the path of the xml file like  `my $xml = "\path\to\test.xml";`

Answer (score 0):

Since XML::Simple is not recommended for new code by the author himself ...

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are
>   available which provide more straightforward and consistent
>   interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.

you might be interested in checking out https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Simple.

> This module is a blunt rewrite of XML::Simple (by Grant McLean) to use
>   the XML::LibXML parser for XML structures, where the original uses
>   plain Perl or SAX parsers.